# SSRS 2005 API Causing Application Pool Crash

Tags: iis, reporting, service, reportingservices-2005, .net-3.5

My site has started having issues with the application pool crashing while using Reporting Services manager.  This is happening at more than one installation.  I have seperated both the Reports and ReportServer web sites into their own application pool to single out the issue and have localized the issue to ReportServer as it is the only app pool that is crashing.

This started at the time we implemented the ReportingServices2005 API.  Attached below is a sample call we use to retrieve the list of reports in an SSRS folder.

Currently our application uses javascript (Jquery) to make ajax calls to a C# .NET function which makes the SSRS API call.

It seems to happen randomly as the app pool will not crash for days or will crash within hours of restarting.  Once this error happens, the app pool rejects all future connections, however the IIS UI does not show that the app pool is stopped.  The httperr log shows that the app pool was disabled due to rapid-fail protection.  When rapid-fail protection is turned off the crash still occurs and the app pool drops all connections.

We have looked at all logs from app pool as well as reporting services.  We have also added the Debug Diagnostics Tool to IIS to retrieve the dump file from the server.  Nothing obvious has jumped out at us and we’re now at a loss.

**Example Reporting Services API Call:**

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = false)]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public List<CatalogItem> GetReportList()
    {
        CatalogItem[] items = null;
        List<CatalogItem> ret = new List<CatalogItem>();
        try
        {
            ReportingService2005 rs = new ReportingService2005();
            rs.Url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Reporting_Services_Url"];
            rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            // Use the reports path in the app config 
            string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServer_ReportList_Path"];

            if (path == null || path == "") path = "/"; // send in at least a base root "/"
            items = rs.ListChildren(path, true);

            foreach (CatalogItem item in items)
            {
                if (item.Type == ItemTypeEnum.Folder || item.Type == ItemTypeEnum.Report)
                {
                    if (item.Name != "Search Reports" && item.Name != "My Reports" && item.Name != "Users Folders" && item.Name != "Data Sources")
                        ret.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Guid? guid = ExceptionPolicy.HandledException(ex);
            // json object to include the guid as well as the exception info, for UI retrieval
            string jsonErrData = AjaxErrorHandling.CreateJsonFormat(guid, ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString());
            throw new Exception(jsonErrData);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

**Dump Log Warning:**

The following threads in Crash_Rule_Targets_*Date*_11_03_2010__Time_09_16_14AM_*w3wp.exe*_ReportServer_*PID*_5256_*371*_Manual Dump.dmp are waiting on data to be returned from another server via WinSock
The call to WinSock originated from 0x02a6a1c3 and is destined for port 80 at IP address 127.0.0.1

( 62 )1.12% of threads blocked

Ensure that any remote server this application may be calling is functioning properly and there are no network issues between the two servers. If the problem continues, please contact the application vendor for further assistance

**Dump Thread in question**:

Thread 62 - System ID 3024
Entry point   mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc
Create time   11/2/2010 7:21:00 PM
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.734
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.156

This thread is waiting on data to be returned from another server via WinSock.

The call to WinSock originated from 0x02a6a1c3 and is destined for port 80 at IP address 127.0.0.1

> WinDbg Dump access on Thread 62 OS Thread Id: 0xbd0 (62) ESP       EIP
>   2b13edb0 7c82860c [NDirectMethodFrameStandalone: 2b13edb0]
>   System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods+OSSOCK.recv(IntPtr, Byte*, Int32,
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags) 2b13edc8 7a581b04
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[], Int32, Int32,
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags, System.Net.Sockets.SocketError ByRef)
>   2b13ee00 7a581a00 System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[], Int32,
>   Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags) 2b13ee20 7a58b854
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32) 2b13ee50
>   7a58b7bb System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32) 2b13ee6c
>   7a58b4aa System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(System.Net.HttpWebRequest,
>   Boolean, Boolean) 2b13eec0 7a58b30a
>   System.Net.Connection.PollAndRead(System.Net.HttpWebRequest, Boolean)
>   2b13eed8 7a58b29b System.Net.ConnectStream.PollAndRead(Boolean)
>   2b13eee4 7a58b132 System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndWriteHeaders(Boolean)
>   2b13ef10 7a58b056
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.WriteHeadersCallback(System.Net.WebExceptionStatus,
>   System.Net.ConnectStream, Boolean) 2b13ef24 7a58ac11
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean) 2b13ef78 7a588f82
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndSubmitRequest() 2b13efa4 7a588e9f
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetRequestSubmitDone(System.Net.ConnectStream)
>   2b13efb8 7a5888c2 System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartRequest(Boolean,
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest, System.Net.TriState) 2b13efe8 7a588233
>   System.Net.Connection.SubmitRequest(System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
>   2b13f02c 7a587bac
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.SubmitRequest(System.Net.HttpWebRequest,
>   System.String) 2b13f064 7a587479
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SubmitRequest(System.Net.ServicePoint)
>   2b13f090 7aaaa4d4 System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() 2b13f0d0
>   65dda7e5
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(System.Net.WebRequest)
>   2b13f100 65dde895
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(System.Net.WebRequest)
>   2b13f104 2f51e76e
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.Global+RSWebServiceWrapper.GetWebResponse(System.Net.WebRequest)
>   2b13f114 65e09905
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(System.String,
>   System.Object[]) 2b13f158 2be6bd5c
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.ReportingService2005.ListSecureMethods()
>   2b13f164 2f51df12
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.RSConnection.GetSecureMethods()
>   2b13f19c 2f51de3a
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.Global+RSWebServiceWrapper.GetSecureMethods()
>   2b13f1c4 2f51dd9b
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.RSConnection.IsSecureMethod(System.String)
>   2b13f1dc 2f51dd13
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.RSConnection.ValidateConnection()
>   2b13f204 2f5197d2 Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.Global.SecureAllAPI()
>   2b13f20c 2f519720
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.EnsureHttpsLevel(Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.HttpsLevel)
>   2b13f218 2f5191e4
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.ReportingPage_Init(System.Object,
>   System.EventArgs) 2b13f260 02a6b30d [MulticastFrame: 2b13f260]
>   System.EventHandler.Invoke(System.Object, System.EventArgs) 2b13f274
>   660ab484 System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(System.EventArgs) 2b13f288
>   660a72ed System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(System.EventArgs) 2b13f294 660ab5de
>   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(System.Web.UI.Control) 2b13f2b4
>   660a7a3b System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean, Boolean)
>   2b13f40c 660a7764 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean, Boolean)
>   2b13f444 660a7691 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() 2b13f47c
>   660a7626
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(System.Web.HttpContext)
>   2b13f488 660a7602
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext) 2b13f49c
>   2f519105 ASP.pages_report_aspx.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext)
>   2b13f4a0 660adad6
>   System.Web.HttpApplication+CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   2b13f4d4 6608132c
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep, Boolean ByRef)
>   2b13f514 6608c5c3
>   System.Web.HttpApplication+ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception)
>   2b13f564 660808ac
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext,
>   System.AsyncCallback, System.Object) 2b13f580 66083e1c
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest)
>   2b13f5b4 66083ac3
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest)
>   2b13f5c4 66082c5c
>   System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr, Int32) 2b13f7d8
>   79f9811e [ContextTransitionFrame: 2b13f7d8]  2b13f80c 79f9811e
>   [GCFrame: 2b13f80c]  2b13f968 79f9811e [ComMethodFrame: 2b13f968]

Answer (score 0):

check your db server health, monitor ReportServer db, and your application database. Run the profiler to catch deadlock, locks, transaction time outs etc.

Disable SSRS cache for time, and see if this error happens again.

Comment: This is happening at multiple clients were the server is not under load at all.  The stored procedures running the reports are complex but return results in enough speed and without failures to rule out the db server health in my eyes.

Comment: I am not sure I follow the SSRS cache.  We have set it to only keep one snapshot of the reports at a time.  But not sure of another setting to remove cache.  Also do you think that a deadlock or transaction timeout in the db would cause the apppool to crash and not just a warning in reporting services.

Answer (score 0):

Anything in the eventlog pertaining to WAS?

Comment: Nothing in the eventlog pertained to WAS.